# How to create Modal/Notification Pop up in Blazor PWA Application?

Tags: c#, notifications, blazor, modal-dialog, popup

I want to create a modal pop up or toast notification in Blazor app,I tried implementing blazor modal but it was giving me errors and didn't show up,I just want a text to show up when I press a certaing button,sort of like $"Hello this is your {code}", i should insert a code value taken from my database.Even a simple html pop up is fine for me.

```
private async void SMSCodePopUp()
{

    var smstext = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 4);
    var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(4, 9);

    await SweetAlertServ.FireAsync(new SweetAlertOptions
        {
            Title = "Confirmation",
            Text = $"SMS Code {smstext}",
            Icon = SweetAlertIcon.Warning,
            ShowCancelButton = true,
            ConfirmButtonText = "Got It"
        });


}
```

Comment: Why not implement one of those already available - search - *blazor modal dialog* or *blazor toast*

Comment: Hello, I ended up using simple BootstrapDialog.

Answer (score 0):

to those who need this too, I just used Bootstrap ModalDialog

```
@if (confirmation)
{
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:block">
        <div class="modal-dialog text-center" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h5 class="modal-title tex-center">SMS Code</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <h5>@smstext</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick=ConfirmClose>Close</button>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {


    private bool confirmation = true;

    string smstext = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 4);


    private void ConfirmClose()
    {
        confirmation = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**